# Problems with the hyphen key

Tags: boot

Problems with the hyphen key, pressing this, the desktop is loose and loses his grip! And the desktop is then displaced in all directions! How do I solve this problem! Bin beginners what it relates to computer, so also in Ubuntu! Thank you for your help!
Greeting Robert!
Excuse my english ! It's a Google translation!

Answer (score 0):

Is your keyboard layout correct? Go into system settings; I think you click the little keyboard icon near the bottom of image three [on WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu) (shown below), and compare the image displayed to the actual keyboard in front of you. If they don't match perfectly, select the correct keyboard layout by following the instructions in that article. (I'm using Debian, so I can't check this now, but I think it's correct.)

[image: Image referenced in text]

Comment: Have now checked and it seems that everything is set correctly! I have a Croatian keyboard and in Croatian it is set! But it really is a stupid problem! Thank you for your help !